# Selenium - assert element exists

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm using Selenium (Django) and am wanting to ensure that before a user logs in the 'login' button is present, but after they log in it is no longer present and is replaced with a 'logout' button.

I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
self.assertFalse(self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Register'))
```

So my question is, how can I use an assert to determine if an element exists on the page please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use if conditional:

```
if self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Register'):
    do your action...
else:
    refresh page.
```

Python gives False, for every None, 0 values. So, if the register field does not exist the conditional will catch the problem.